# Incompatibility issues (AndroidManifest)

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-compatibility

I've encountered some difficulties on the setting of the manifest file. It seems that some users are not able to download my application due to compatibility issues.

My app doesn't require anything special so I just would like to understand which are the best options to set in the manifest file..

For now I've:

```
<supports-screens 
 android:anyDensity="true" 
 android:resizeable="true" 
 android:normalScreens="true" 
 android:xlargeScreens="true" 
 android:largeScreens="true" 
 android:smallScreens="false" />
```

and

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="10"/>
```

Some of the users (or maybe all of them) that encountered this problem have modded roms.
Is there something that I should care about modded roms?

Comment: Here it is: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.enrichman.roma3free (are you able to download it?)

Comment: Yes, its installed only on my `Motorola xoom` not my `Samsung Galaxy s2`

Comment: And I've a SGS2 too (and I'm able to download it...). Is it yours modded?

Comment: With a cooked rom. I've the original one (ics).

Comment: I'm also having original ics.

Comment: Ok, at least we understood that it's not related to the rom.. : /